# High-resolution maps using the HERE Maps API

Tags: here-api

How would I display a high-resolution map similar to the one at https://beta.here.com using the HERE Maps API for JavaScript?

From the [API reference](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-options.html) there is an option to change the `pixelRatio` when creating a map.

```
var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),
    defaultLayers.normal.map,
    { pixelRatio: 2 }
);
```

This works great and produces a high-resolution map on high-DPI screens, however, this changes the scale of the map and all map objects become small and text becomes difficult to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PPI settings aren't documented very well in the JavaScript API reference, but is documented in the [Map Tile API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-service-platform.html).

> Pixels per inch. Resolution that can be requested, valid values are:
>   72 – normal, used by default if no value provided
>   250 – mobile
>   320 – hi-res

You can specify the PPI when creating a default layer (second option).

```
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(512, 320);

var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),
    defaultLayers.normal.map,
    { pixelRatio: 2 }
);
```

Comment: Using `pixelRatio: 2` will make all labels etc. quite small and unreadable - how can I produce high resolution tiles like on https://wego.here.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also ask the window:

var hidpi = ('devicePixelRatio' in window && devicePixelRatio > 1);

and create the default Layers like this:

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers(hidpi ? 512 : 256, hidpi ? 320 : null);

Comment: Using `pixelRatio: 2` will make all labels etc. quite small and unreadable - how can I produce high resolution tiles like on https://wego.here.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone using the HereMap tiles without the Javascript API (such as through Leaflet), the crucial parameters are `&ppi=250` (`&ppi=72` for low-dpi) and `/512/` instead of `/256/` after the `{z}/{x}/{y}`.