# How to change dimension and colour of the default Marker on Here Maps API for Javascript v3?

Tags: here-api

I am looking for a way to change dimension of the default marker on the Here Maps API for Javascript v3. I need to do this because I implemented, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27542746/3717575), a different pixel ratio for smartphones/tablet... But on them the marker looks really small, almost impossible to be used! Also, I would like to change the colour of the default marker, in order to highlight a marker after a search.
Is there a way to do such a thing?

Eventually, if it is not possible, some of you has the SVG of the default marker?

Comment: You can find the SVG code for a colored `H.Marker` in this stackoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020199/here-nokia-maps-javascript-api-3-0-explorer-how-to-set-maker-color)

Comment: Based on what is set the style of SVG? Also, why if I double the width and height the point moves to a completely different point?

Comment: I believe that Here Maps supports SVG mini. If your `H.Marker` appears to be "moving" when you zoom out, then it is likely that either the SVG definition or the [anchor](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-icon-options.html#h-map-icon-options__anchor) point has been defined incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah, most likely. However I have just tried to use a `DomMarker` instead of a regular `Marker` and I don't need any more to manage the dimension of the marker, now it's always displayed at the same size. (but I'm still interested in knowing if there is a way through the regular Marker to change it's size dynamically.

Comment: Dug through the API reference, seems impossible to change the size of the default marker icon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no other way to do this.
As said, I moved from a regular Marker to a DomMarker which is displayed exactly the same dimension with every pixelratio.